# Webstorm/Intellij put ";" always at the end of line

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In eclipse there is a setting to put an ";" automatically at the end of line even if the cursor is not at the end. Exists such a setting WebStorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA it's done via the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There is also a [request to do it automatically](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-4743), feel free to vote.