# IntelliJ equivalent to Eclipse TAB

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse to IDEA. In Eclipse, when I hit the TAB key while typing in function parameters and in other contextual situations it will forward the cursor to the next place I can type (next parameter, end of the line for semi-colon, etc.). I use it constantly. Is there a way to get similar functionality in IDEA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not direct equivalent to this action. See [completion features](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Completion+features) page for the advanced features.

Regarding the semicolon insertion see [Webstorm/Intellij put ";" always at the end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548075/webstorm-intellij-put-always-at-the-end-of-line/8548510#8548510).

See also [Things possible in Eclipse that aren’t possible in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461255/things-possible-in-eclipse-that-arent-possible-in-intellij).