# Easy toggling to next parameter in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say you are in a method with two parameters and you filled the first one:

`foo("test",`

so the caret is right after second "t" letter. It's possible to hit `Tab` and caret moves just after the comma in Eclipse. Is there such a feature in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the related question: [IntelliJ equivalent to Eclipse TAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621006) and [vote for this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74666) in YouTrack.