# Autocomplete Quotes - Get out from within Quotes and Move the Cursor after the Closing Cursor

Tags: pycharm

I like that it autocompletes single and double quotes, but how do I "get out" from within the quotes and move the cursor to the right side of the closing quote?

Example, I start typing:

```py
string = 'Hello World'
```

After I'm done with the letter d, my cursor is stuck there.

So is there a fancy way of hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> so that I can move the cursor to the right side out of the closing quote?

Comment: I'd like that very much. Just like Tab does in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to accomplish this without moving your fingers to the END or the Right arrow key is to just type the quotation mark.

It will overwrite the closing quotation mark and you end up right where you want.

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm doesn't have this feature, see the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621920/104891).

Please also vote for this feature request request to make it implemented faster:

- [IDEA-74666](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74666) Add Eclipse Style Paren/Bracket/Quote Completiton

Comment: They just fixed it in May. The feature is disabled by default, you can enable it in Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys->Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way of achieving it in pycharm is hitting the same quotation (single or double) after u finish typing the text in the quotations.
Eg.

Typing: <kbd>'</kbd> then `hello world` then <kbd>'</kbd> gives --> `'hello world'|`

The first `'` will give you this --> `'|'`
The second quotation `'` will push your cursor outside the end quotation.

Comment: Though this basically is a duplicate to taikki's answer, maybe you want to add the hint that `' + hello world + '` should be interpreted as keystrokes, as this could easily be mistaken as an assignment in python. (At least I was confused when reading it first and it took me a bit to understand it.)

Comment: @Kim Does it make a little bit more sense now? I'll remove it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The linked feature request [mentions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984#comment=27-1274315) another workaround:

Add Shift-Space as another shortcut for right arrow. Makes it quicker to type in comparison to reach for the arrow key.

Answer (score 1):

**Press Tab.**

You can now just press Tab to move outside the quote mark.

It should work by default, but if not you can enable the option in Preferences->Editor->General->SmartKeys and enable "Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab when typing"

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want(ed) to move the caret to the end of the line.

From this:

```
print "Hello World|"
```

To this:

```
print "Hello World"|
```

This is achieved using the END key.

PyCharm's Keymap is found in:
File Settings > Appearance > Keymap

Comment: Does not help in many situations. It's rather common to be in nested parentheses or quotes and you want to move out of the inner block, not all to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** which completes the current statement and takes you to the next line.